# Can't open URL, selenium webdriver chrome in express route

Tags: express, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm having trouble trying to work selenium webdriver in one of my express routes.

here is the code:

```
var router = Router();

/* WEBDRIVER */
var webdriver = require("selenium-webdriver"),
    By        = webdriver.By,
    until     = webdriver.until,
    chrome    = require("selenium-webdriver/chrome"),
    path      = require("chromedriver").path;

/* ROUTE */
router.get('/', function(request, response) {
    const URL = "https://secure24.ipayment.com/NYCPayments/nycbookmark_1.htm";

    var service = new chrome.ServiceBuilder(path).build();
    chrome.setDefaultService(service);

    var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome())
    .build();

    driver.get(URL);
    response.send("done");

});
```

any thoughts on what might be the issue?

Here is the console log to the driver.get(URL), I cannot make sense of it.

```
ManagedPromise {
  flow_:
   ControlFlow {
     propagateUnhandledRejections_: true,
     activeQueue_:
      TaskQueue {
        name_: 'TaskQueue::3',
        flow_: [Circular],
        tasks_: [Object],
        interrupts_: null,
        pending_: null,
        subQ_: null,
        state_: 'new',
        unhandledRejections_: Set {} },
     taskQueues_: Set { [Object] },
     shutdownTask_: null,
     hold_:
      ZoneTask {
        runCount: 0,
        type: 'macroTask',
        zone: [Object],
        source: 'setInterval',
        data: [Object],
        scheduleFn: [Function: scheduleTask],
        cancelFn: [Function: clearTask],
        callback: [Function],
        invoke: [Function],
        ref: [Function: bound ],
        unref: [Function: bound ] } },
  stack_:
   { Task: WebDriver.navigate().to(https://secure24.ipayment.com/NYCPayments/nycbookmark_1.htm)
       at thenableWebDriverProxy.schedule (/Users/shaunchua/Documents/Shaun's Stuff/Professional Work/WinIt/winit-internal/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:816:17)
       at Navigation.to (/Users/shaunchua/Documents/Shaun's Stuff/Professional Work/WinIt/winit-internal/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:1140:25)
       at thenableWebDriverProxy.get (/Users/shaunchua/Documents/Shaun's Stuff/Professional Work/WinIt/winit-internal/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:997:28)
       at /Users/shaunchua/Documents/Shaun's Stuff/Professional Work/WinIt/winit-internal/dist/server/index.js:56871:28
       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/shaunchua/Documents/Shaun's Stuff/Professional Work/WinIt/winit-internal/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
       at next (/Users/shaunchua/Documents/Shaun's Stuff/Professional Work/WinIt/winit-internal/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
       at Route.dispatch (/Users/shaunchua/Documents/Shaun's Stuff/Professional Work/WinIt/winit-internal/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/shaunchua/Documents/Shaun's Stuff/Professional Work/WinIt/winit-internal/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
       at /Users/shaunchua/Documents/Shaun's Stuff/Professional Work/WinIt/winit-internal/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
       at Function.process_params (/Users/shaunchua/Documents/Shaun's Stuff/Professional Work/WinIt/winit-internal/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12) name: 'Task' },
  parent_: null,
  callbacks_: null,
  state_: 'pending',
  handled_: false,
  value_: undefined,
  queue_: null }
```

Comment: Please edit the post and add the error information for better debugging. Thanks :)

Comment: that's the thing, there isn't an error

Comment: What does the console say?

Comment: Listening on: http://localhost:3000
    GET /ipayment-status 304 25.809 ms - -